# Can we determine at runtime if two type_info's would be castable?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, typeid, typeinfo

Is there a way to determine from two `const ::std::type_info` objects, let's name them `B` and `D` if the type described by D is derived from type B?

I ask because I want to erase the type of an object I get but later on be able to check if it can be safely promoted.

```
void* data;
const ::std::type_info* D;

template<typename D>
void store(D&& object)
{
    D = &typeid(object);
    data = ::std::addressof(object);
}

template<typename B>
B& load()
{
    // if(typeid(B) != (*D)) throw ::std::bad_cast{};
    return *reinterpret_cast<B*>(data); // <- also problematic
}
```

I want to be able to use it like this:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : Base {};

Derived d;
store(d);
// ....
load<Base>();
```

Thus it is not suitable to just use an equality compare for the typeids. I am pretty sure this could be possible in a similar way that dynamic_cast can figure this out. What I want is that in every case where `D&` could be assigned to `B&` allowing B as the type argument of `load()` - without knowing `D` at that time.

Comment: not sure if this helps you, but you can use `std::is_base_of` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of from the very beginning

Comment: Not after I erased the type of the passed in data. It is meant that I can pass information from one thread to another without knowing the exact type.

Comment: I see... maybe you can think about a different design then, it looks a bit strange right now

Comment: `*reinterpret_cast<B*>(data)` That doesn't work, in general, even if `D` is in fact derived from `B`. Nothing says that a `B` subobject is at offset 0 within `D` object.

Comment: marked that I'm not sure about the whole method, not only the check

Comment: Well, if you can't get the correct pointer back anyway, then the issue of type introspection becomes rather moot, doesn't it? In my humble opinion, this whole approach ain't gonna fly.

Comment: I added a sentence to the question, maybe that clears it up a bit - as the title tells you, I accept a justified "No, that is not possible"

Comment: What's up with taking the address of a temporary?  You know that won't be sufficient to keep the object alive until the other thread is done using it, right?

Comment: Yes I know that, but sadly it's a neccessary evil for compatibilty, I should probably specialized for rvalues and static_assert in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to let the compiler and interal mechanism to figure it out for me. I don't have a problem with cross compiling, in that case `::std::type_info` isn't consistent, either.

```
typedef void (*throw_op)(void*);
throw_op dataThrow;

template<typename T>
[[ noreturn ]] void throwing(void* data)
{
    throw static_cast<T*>(data);
}
[[ noreturn ]] void bad_cast()
{
    throw ::std::bad_cast{};
}

template<typename B>
B& poly_load()
{
    if(data == nullptr)
        bad_cast();
    try {
        dataThrow(data);
    } catch (B* ptr) {
        return *ptr;
    } catch (...) {
        bad_cast();
    }
}
```

All you have to do is add the following line to the store operation:

```
dataThrow = throwing<D>;
```

---

How does this work? It takes advantages of exceptions and how they are caught. Note here that this makes `poly_load` ?much? slower than the simple `load` function, thus I'll keep the both around.

C++ says that when an exception of type `D*` is being thrown you can catch that exception with a catch-clause `B*` where `B` is any ancestor of `D`.

Minimal example:

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived : public virtual Base {
    void foo() override {
        ::std::cout << "Hello from Derived" << ::std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d{};
    store(d);

    // .....

    poly_load<Base>().foo();
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant!  It's the second time I've seen a missing language feature implemented by introducing exceptions.  (The other one was thread-local storage)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should be using an equality test on your `type_info` instances.

`reinterpret_cast` provides no guarantees except when casting back to the exact original type.  Even

```
Derived* d = get_derived();
Base* b = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(d);
```

will not give a correct result (if the `Base` subobject is not stored at offset zero within `Derived`, which is guaranteed only for standard-layout types).

The complete rule is found in section 5.2.10:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.     When a prvalue `v` of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type "pointer to *`cv`* `T`", the result is `static_cast<` *`cv`*
>   `T*>(static_cast<` *`cv`* `void*>(v))`.  Converting a prvalue of type "pointer to `T1`" to the type "pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value.

Only `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` can perform base subobject adjustments, and those don't kick in when either type is `void*` (after type erasure).

However, it appears that the Boost developers have worked out all the difficulties. See `boost::variant::polymorphic_get`

Comment: How is an equality test on `type_info` covariant?

Comment: @pqnet: It isn't.  There is no support in `reinterpret_cast` for either up- or down-casts.

Comment: I've read about virtual inheritance after asking the question and realized that it would be really hard (not impossible though) to handle all cases. I think with some support by the standard it should be possible to extract the correct offset to the base class. But it doesn't look like that is coming soon - since it looks a lot like compile-time reflection.

Comment: @WorldSEnder: You probably want to look at boost's implementation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/polymorphic_get.html

Comment: on the other hand boost::variant is not really the same thing, boost::any is closer to what I am looking for

Comment: @WorldSEnder: Oh right, that would be why I was surprised to see Boost making it work.  `boost::any` of course only has the equivalent of `get()`, not `polymorphic_get()`.

Comment: If you are still interested, I think I found a way to do it, have a look at my own answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

The self-answer with exceptions is pretty cool. Here's a self-contained version:

```
class polymorphic_erasure {
    std::function< void() > throw_self;

public:
    template< typename static_type >
    polymorphic_erasure( static_type & o )
        : throw_self( [ & o ] { throw & o; } )
        {}

    polymorphic_erasure()
        : throw_self( [] { throw std::bad_cast(); } )
        {}

    template< typename want_type >
    want_type & get() const {
        try {
            throw_self();
        } catch ( want_type * result ) {
            return * result;
        } catch ( ... ) {}
        throw std::bad_cast();
    }
};
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a12114a210c77a45

Note, though, that you can't assign with a polymorphic base type and then `get` the derived object — you still need a `dynamic_cast` for that. And there's no RTTI or polymorphism here. (Perhaps it needs a different name.) Although exceptions do use RTTI for classes, `polymorphic_erasure` only throws pointers. The exception-based functionality is complementary: It classifies the object into a type hierarchy and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only reliable and portable method for determining derivation is to use dynamic_cast in a try catch block. If it's cast-able, it won't throw a bad_cast exception. Do this test in the your store routine, if it doesn't throw, store the data, otherwise set it to NULL.  Don't forget to check for that in your load routine.

Comment: For `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`, if both `T` is a pointer type and `v` has pointer type, the type of `v` must be a pointer to a complete class type. `void` is not a complete class type. Furthermore, the runtime type check when casting from a base class to a derived class requires the base class to be polymorphic (i.e. to have at least one virtual function). Typically, the vtable is used for the check. When all you have is a `void*`, you don't even know if the object it points to *has* a vptr.

Comment: I thought we were up-casting, but you are right, the type is washed out by the cast to void* in the above code.

Comment: There is no runtime check for casting to a base class, since that check can be performed at compile-time. -- I think the OP has multiple independent hierarchies, i.e. multiple independent base classes, so OP cannot cast to a common base class in the `store` function.

Comment: I just want to confirm what @dyp said, I have not common base class, the data could be `any`thing - and boost.any doesn't implement a solution to my problem either.

Answer (score -1):

what about something like this:

```
void* data;

class Wrapper{ virtual ~Wrapper()=0; };
template<typename T> class SpecificWrapper: public Wrapper {
    public:
        T* value;
        Wrapper(T* ptr): value(ptr){}
        ~Wrapper() {}
}

template<typename D>
void store(D&& object)
{
    Wrapper* wrapper = new SpecificWrapper<D>(&object);
    if(data!= ::std::nullptr)
        delete reinterpret_cast<Wrapper*>(data);
    data = (void*)wrapper;
}

template<typename B>
B& load()
{
    //always safe because we know type being correct
    Wrapper *w = reinterpret_cast<Wrapper*>(data);
    SpecificWrapper<B> * w1 = dynamic_cast<SpecificWrapper<B>>(w);

    if(w1==::std::nullptr) throw ::std::bad_cast{};

    return w1->value;
}
```

The idea is to use a wrapper type hierarchy to do the type erasure while keeping type information. In this way you can statically determine that the type of the `data` variable even if it is declared as `void*` is always the top level `Wrapper` class, allowing you to always perform safe casts. You need to be careful of the lifetime of the wrapper object though...

Comment: Just use `Wrapper* data` and lose 80% of those casts.  And note that the `dynamic_cast` will return `null` unless `B` is exactly `D`, C++ templates aren't covariant.

Comment: yeh but there may be a reason he need to use `void*` (maybe C callback library?). The `void*` part is a requirement, and part of the interface so I didn't suggest to change that. `reinterpret_cast` are safe and no cost if you can prove that the type you are casting to is correct one. You are correct about covariance, I should add a note about that.

Comment: Worse, you're storing the address of a temporary.

Comment: I'm not doing it, it was part of the question so I believe the OP has a reason to be sure that address is at least safe.